# Приложение падает SIGSEGV при проверке Даты на валидность или на NULL

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql

Запросом получил из базы POSTGRES значения ДатыВремени. В базе значение DateTimeEND NULL, соответственно в переменную дожно положиться NULL, но при проверке или на валидность или на NULL `( if( !m_dtDateTimeBGN.isNULL() ) )`
приложение падает SIGSEGV. Пытался инициализировать пустым конструктором  `m_dtDateTimeEND = QDateTime();`но результат тот же.

```
    ...
         QDateTime m_dtDateTimeBGN;
         QDateTime m_dtDateTimeEND;
    ...

if( !oSqlRecord.value( "BGN_DATE" ).isNull() )
    {
        m_dtDateTimeBGN = oSqlRecord.value( "BGN_DATE" ).toDateTime() ;
    }
    else
    {
        m_dtDateTimeBGN = QDateTime();
    }

    if( !oSqlRecord.value( "END_DATE" ).isNull() )
    {
       m_dtDateTimeEND = oSqlRecord.value( "END_DATE" ).toDateTime();
    }
    else
    {

        m_dtDateTimeEND = QDateTime();
    }



QString CLiqMeterCommissioning::getPeriodLiqMeter() const
    {
        QString sPeriod;
        if( !m_dtDateTimeBGN.isValid() )
        {
            if( !m_dtDateTimeEND.isValid() )// Здесь падает
            {
                sPeriod = MainWindow::AMR_TR( "Был в эксплуатации с %1 до %2" )
                        .arg( m_dtDateTimeBGN.toString( "dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm" ) )
                        .arg( m_dtDateTimeEND.toString( "dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm" ) );
            }
            else
            {
                sPeriod = MainWindow::AMR_TR( "В эксплуатации с %1" )
                        .arg( m_dtDateTimeBGN.toString( "dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm" ) );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if( !m_dtDateTimeEND.isValid() )
            {
                sPeriod = MainWindow::AMR_TR( "Был в эксплуатации до %1" )
                        .arg( m_dtDateTimeEND.toString( "dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm" ) );
            }
            else
            {    }
        }

        return sPeriod;
    }
```

Comment: Минимально воспроизводимый пример бы, а то не ясно что такое m_dtDateTimeBGN

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Это поля класса. Вопрос изменил.

Comment: А откуда мы знаем, что `getPeriodLiqMeter` вызывается раньше чем код с инициализацией? :D

Comment: @gil9red Вы правы! Функция, которая инициализирует параметры не возвращала значение, при этом компилятор почему то не ругался.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что функция, которая загружает параметры из базы, а затем инициализирует члены объекта не возвращала значения, при этом основная логика не ломалась и проблема была явно не воспроизводима. При всем при этом компилятор почему то не ругался на отсутствие оператора return

```
DatabaseStruct::CLiqMeterCommissioning CDatabaseDriverPSQL::load_liq_commissioning( const QUuid &oCommissioningUuid )
{
    AMR::DatabaseStruct::CLiqMeterCommissioning oLiqMetCommissioning;
    if( !oCommissioningUuid.isNull() )
    {
        oLiqMetCommissioning.m_oLiqCommissioningUUid = oCommissioningUuid;

        AMR::Database::CQueryResult oQueryResult = select_liq_commissioning( oCommissioningUuid );
        if( !oQueryResult.isError() )
        {
            if( oQueryResult.oSqlQuery.first() )
            {
                QSqlRecord oSqlRecord = oQueryResult.oSqlQuery.record();
                oLiqMetCommissioning.setCommissioningParams( oSqlRecord );

                return oLiqMetCommissioning; // строка отсутствовала
            }
        }
        else AMR_ASSERT_FALSE();
    }
    else AMR_ASSERT_FALSE();

    return DatabaseStruct::CLiqMeterCommissioning(); // строка отсутствовала
}
```

Comment: Потому что явный `return` не является обязательным. Но обычно в таких случаях бывает хотя бы [предупреждение](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1pSxKzR0e1d2OXQC).